# Picasso only loading one image

Tags: android, picasso

So I've checked the size of "parsedPhotoStrings" and it's clearly greater than 1. However, only one image is displayed with the following code. I'm not sure what is going on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
                    String photoUrl = createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
                    Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).resize(width, 0).into(imageView);
                    photoLayout.addView(imageView);
                }
```

EDIT:

Multiple photos are showing! I overlooked my orientation of the layout. However, the cache is still not clearing even after .netWorkPolicy(NetWorkPolicy_CLEAR_CACHE) and .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.CLEAR_CACHE)

EDIT:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
                String photoUrl = createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
                photoLayout.addView(imageView);
                Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl)
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
                        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                        .resize(width, 0)
                        .into(imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(0);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).invalidate(photoUrl);
            }
```

I've tried so many things to clear the cache. Still got nothing working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try this ,alteast you would know if there was an error   

  `Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
            
                                    }
            
                                    @Override
                                    public void onError() {
            
                                    }
                                });`

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the order.

Add the `ImageView` then load image:

Change this to

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
    String photoUrl = createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
    Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).resize(width, 0).into(imageView);
    photoLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

This

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
    String photoUrl = createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
    photoLayout.addView(imageView);                    
    Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).resize(width, 0).into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: When adding this code, I see other images for a fleeting moment. In a second, the latest image is only displayed.

Comment: try reverse this lines  photoLayout.addView(imageView);                    
    Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).resize(width, 0).into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

try this use `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`

```
Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).resize(width, 0).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);
```

**sample code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
   String photoUrl = createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
   photoLayout.addView(imageView);
   Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this).load(photoUrl).resize(width, 0).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to caching. You have to implement this:-

```
Picasso.with(YourActivity.this)                                            
.load(childjson.getString("your_string"))
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.skipMemoryCache()
.into(yourImagePreview);
```

And just make sure to change dependency of picasso in build.gradle with:-

```
compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
```

This will support no memory caching.
Happy Coding!

Comment: skipMemoryCache() is deprecated. This is not working in my case. The Android Monitor still increases cache of the app when more images are loaded eventually resulting in an OutOfMemoryException. Additionally, only one image, the final image is still being displayed? Could it be my loop logic?

Comment: yeah! you can try If condition as well, just check if(imageview != null). Hope it may works for you

Comment: I tried. I also created a PicassoUtilities class to access the cache, and I clear cache after loading and adding image to layout. Still doesn't fix the problem. Is it possible something else is being cached?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the image is caching ht eurl,if so add the code to invalidate() the url.This wil remove previous cache.

```
Picasso.with(this).invalidate(url);
```

Second check for the network cachcing mechanism.This code will make no caching for the images

```
Picasso.networkPolicy(NetworkUtils.isConnected(this) ?
                        NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE : NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
```

So you code should be like

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedPhotoStrings.size(); i++) {
        String photoUrl =createPlacePhotosUrl(parsedPhotoStrings.get(i));
        Picasso.with(this).invalidate(url);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MarkerActivity.this);
        photoLayout.addView(imageView);

        Picasso.with(MarkerActivity.this)
                .load(photoUrl)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkUtils.isConnected(this) ?
                        NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE : NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE); 
                .resize(width, 0)
                .into(imageView);
}
```

Also to support these code you need picasso version 2.5.+

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: NetworkUtils cannot be resolved. I checked the gradle dependency version and I do add 2.5.2. Am I overlooking something really simple?

Comment: I dint get you.previously which version you were using?

Comment: I am using 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' so there shouldn't be a problem.